# link_to file with whitespaces in name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

How should I link to a file in my Rails public folder, if the filename has spaces in it?
i.e.:

```html
<%=link_to 'Download my file', root_url + "files/my file.zip"%>
```

Comment: "files/my file.zip".gsub(' ', '%20')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [URI.escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) it will take care of escaping the string for you.

```
URI.escape("files/my file.zip")
=> "files/my%20file.zip"
```

Comment: Updated version fails when the file contains '/' i.e. 'File for Windows 9x/NT/2000'. It would solve the whitespace issue, but the helper itself does not work as expected!

Comment: @AndrewRukin You are making a web request, the path separator is always "/".

Comment: URI.escape  seems to be the Rails Way, and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify route in `config/routes.rb` (use own controller and action):

```
get '/*path', as: :file, controller: :main, action: :file
```

and build links use `file_url` or `file_path` helpers:

```
file_path(path: 'files/my file.zip')
```

it will return:

```
/files/my%20file.zip
```